# Parental controls - I can't add time

Tags: parental-controls

I am at the end of my rope with parental controls.  I set up time of day restrictions and daily time limits on my daughters computer to limit screen time by default.

From time to time I want to extend these limits:

add time past the limit i.e. 4 hours
extend past the time of day restrictions i.e. past 8 PM

I can't seem to do that at all.  My daughter tries to login and then hits the parental controls lock.  She can get to the prompt to add time with admin user etc.  I enter my password and then her account just kicks back to the login screen.  I have a hunch that you can't go past the time of day restriction but the daily time limit should not be an issue.

Anyone else see this or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: iOS or macOS? If former, are you managing from within her account or do you have another iOS device to check from? I manage my son’s screen time from my own device, going into Screen Time -> Family to change settings.

Comment: MacOS.  iOS seems ok and the control is actually better in my opinion.

Comment: Hmm. My prior experience with parental controls in macOS was so wonderful that I stopped using it altogether. It does seem to work well on iOS though as you say.

Comment: I recently started experiencing this on 10.13.6/High Sierra. Years ago OS X parental controls worked flawlessly for us on my iMac; recently we've tried setting them up on a 2011 MacBook Pro and it's buggy as hell in many ways other than this one. I realize it's a long time since this question's been asked, but thought I'd take a chance and see if you ever resolved this.